# Check if extension is installed, and close tab if user removes extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

This is how things work in my website `a.com` , users visit my website and I talk to a person in another website `b.com` using my account , generate a link `b.com/somelink` and redirect user to that link.

Here is the problem , this address `b.com/somelink` contains some private information which I want to hide from visitors ... since I don't control that website I can't to that.

So i thought the best option would be a browser extension, users would have to install the extension before redirecting to b.com.

So here is my simple extension:

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "extname",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "extnameExtension!",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ,  "webNavigation"
  ] ,

  "content_scripts": [
    {

      "matches": ["*://b.com/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ]

}
```

contentscript.js

```
function fireOnReady() {
    document.getElementById('personal-info').innerHTML = 'some dummy data';
}
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    fireOnReady();
} else {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fireOnReady);
}
```

which is working fine, but I have 2 problems:

1 - Users might disable the extension and refresh the page `b.com/somelink` and see my personal info .... so my solution is to close browser tab opening `b.com` if they remove my extension ... is there any way to do this? (this link is only available if they redirected from my website to b.com so they cant just copy/paste the link in new tab/browser )

2 - In my own website, how can i make sure they have installed my extension before redirecting them to b.com ?

**please lets not talk about scenario that i explained or other solution or ...i know this might sound odd, but this is not intended for public users but private special group who will install extension if they have to,  im interested to know how to do this with code and extensions  even if i find another solution **

Comment: I am completely confused by this explanation. Easiest solution I can think of - if you want to hide the content of b.com/somelink, then take down that server, or erase all private information you have there. If any external computer program can access it without some kind of authentication, all programs can see it. Even if you can rephrase your issue, a browser extension sounds like a terrible solution and no one would install it.

Comment: @Katana314 thanx for the answering , i dont want to spend too much time  talking about stuff other than code/extension but to point some of your concerns 

1 - there is a authentication step ... its done trough my website and i generate a link with expiration and then redirect user to that link (`b.com/somelink`)  you cant just open this link without going trough my website 

2 -  i offer valuable service on a private/special field ... its not for public users and yes they will install it

Comment: The private information will still be visible in network trace after pressing F12 in most browsers!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are proposing is to redirect users to the page that contains private information, and then when your extension detects that the page has loaded, scrub that information from the DOM. Quite irrespective of the two question you ask about extensions, I would not use the approach you are proposing, because:

1. **The private information is *still* sent to the user's browser, and it is still accessible to the user**. As [iPirat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52859711/check-if-extension-is-installed-and-close-tab-if-user-remove-extension#comment92727731_52859711) alluded to, it is possible, using the developer's tools in just about any browser to see the data that the browser receives. The network tab will contain the request for the page and *will show the original HTML* that was sent to the browser, and the information you want to hide will be visible right there. There's no fix for this, *short of not sending the information in the first place.*
2. **Failures in your extension are liable to expose the sensitive data.** You said you do not control the site on which the private information is shown, which means that you do not get to control the `personal-info` ID of the element which contains your private information. If the designers of that side decide to change the ID to `personal-user-info`, then your extension fails and the private data is visible.

   And this is irrespective of bugs in your code. You make a typo somewhere, your extension does not run, and the sensitive information is visible to the user.

I would rethink your entire approach. One commonly used way to ensure that the private information is never ever in the hands of your users is to have your front end code get the information it needs from the third-party site (`b.com`) through a server on your site (`a.com`). Your server can get the information from `b.com` and include only what **must** be passed on to your users.

Answer (score 1):

`a.com` could embed `b.com/somelink` as an iframe, but don't show the iframe unless it receives a signal from the extension.

`a.com` Javascript:

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = 'b.com/somelink';
setInterval(() => {
    if (!document.body.classList.contains('extension-token')) window.close();
    else if (!document.body.contains(iframe)) document.body.append(iframe);
    document.body.classList.remove('extension-token');
}, 10000);
```

`a.com` content script:

```
setInterval(() => {
   document.body.classList.add('extension-token');
}, 5000);
```

This is of course not a safe solution.

Comment: any solution with client side script can be hacked by any user, even not a very dedicated user.

Answer (score 0):

As IPirat and Luis have said browser extension is not a secure way in your case  . User can disable it, user can see original html in network tab of debuger, user can run another browser where you have no extension to modify page. You have just two option to move forward:

1. You have to create server side script which will load b.com/somelink, modifiy it and send to the user the page without your private data.
2. You can create your own browser. For example it is quite easy to create webbrowser with C# or VBA for windows using visual studio. You can share b.com/somelinkmodified which will be converted to b.com/somelink in your browser and will not be accessible with any of other browsers. Thus, your  users have to install your browser to see generated page. Than your browser will open this link, will  load the page, modify and than show only desired information

Comment: A note on the create your own browser idea; a dedicated enough user will still be be able to access the sensitive information, as the custom browser is still receiving that data from the server. The information will be visible through a packet inspection utility like wireshark, or through directly inspecting the browser process's memory. The only really foolproof way to hide the information is to do it server-side.

Comment: Yes there are advanced users who can do any hack to get any data but a huge percent of users can't do so (Especially if  connection is under SSL). Thus, own browser can help to achieve desired result and it is the simplest way in this case.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply ask the user to install your Chrome App on your website and then perform the code (obtain link, send redirect) on the Chrome App. You can make the Chrome App essentially a frontend (you can even duplicate the HTML) and do all the logic there. You will have full control of the information since your Chrome App is the one performing the redirect. In fact, your Chrome App can launch windows without address bar among other interesting things you can do. You might even be able to make a http call internally and spit out the response html; this way you complete hide the parameters in the URL link (I assume that's where you are afraid the personal information would be).

I actually have a Chrome App that acts as a portal which does what you want (without it being the intention). The Chrome App would log the users in and the open up windows to different website if needed; sometimes it literally displays the content in the app itself (without exposing any URL to the common user).

Comment: What if user uses not chrome browser?

Comment: That seems more like a question for the OP since he tagged the question with google-chrome, google-chrome-extension and google-chrome-app, lol...